# Postgres resource usage stats and configs

Tags: postgresql, optimization, server, postgresql-9.4

I'm using postgres server 9.4. 
From pg_admin or psql tool, I can do `SHOW ALL;`  this will give me the config of postgres server. For example `shared_buffers is 8GB` or `effective_cache_size is 24GB`

Recently the database has grown bigger and queries become slower.
I do aware that the query may need to be re-evaluated using `explain`.

Query optimization aside, how do I know the utilization status?
For example from this `shared_buffer` of 8GB or `effective_cache_size` of 24GB how much is being used, or any other config value - is it time to increase these config value?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html

shared_buffers = 8GB is already huge value, you can examine it up to some level with https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgbuffercache.html
If you still feel it is not enough, keep in mind you might need increase max_wal_size. Also before 9.4 or 9.5 (not sure, it definetely happens on 9.3) streaming replication slave uses only one core to scan shared_buffers for not used deleted pages, so servers with big shared_buffers are awfully lagging. Those two arguments against increase that comes from the top of the head.

changing `effective_cache_size` is even more surprising idea. Usually it is set to max value from the beginning. As it basically tells planner how much RAM he can count on. So you might want to reduce it if you install new software that eats up RAM, and increase if you add more RAM to the machine. Otherwise - why planner should expect more RAM available for query?..

The above is my personal humble experience with those two configs. Answering your question I'd say try `pg_buffercache` to check `shared_buffers` usage and check execution plans with `set effective_cache_size to some_bigger_value` - if you see that Postgres started using indexes it was not using with smaller value and execution speeds up - it's time to increase it cluster wise.